# How to disable the Calculate Cells option before opening the workbook?

Tags: excel

I've got an Excel workbook that's got some crazy calculations in it. I managed to close it but every time I open it it just goes into calculation mode! Since it's calculating I can't go into options to change calculation status to manual for this workbook. And pressing ESC doesn't help.

Is there a way to disable calculations without opening the workbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel calculation mode is an application-level setting that is set from the first workbook opened, but stored in every saved workbook.

So open some other workbook that is set to Manual Calculation before the crazy calculation workbook.